Running a Function Multiple Times
I have this R code I wrote:
flipCoinPoissonTimes <- function() {
    lambda <- 5  # initial parameter for the Poisson distribution
    num_flips <- rpois(1, lambda)  # generate a random number from a Poisson distribution

p <- 0.5  # initial probability of heads
set <- 1  # initial set number
results <- data.frame(set=integer(), turn_number=integer(), value_of_p=numeric(), result=character(), lambda=numeric(), num_flips=integer())

while(TRUE) {
    for (turn_number in 1:num_flips) {
        flip <- runif(1)  # generate a random number between 0 and 1
        if (flip < p) {
            results <- rbind(results, data.frame(set=set, turn_number=turn_number, value_of_p=p, result="Heads", lambda=lambda, num_flips=num_flips))
            return(results)  # stop once the first head is observed
        } else {
            results <- rbind(results, data.frame(set=set, turn_number=turn_number, value_of_p=p, result="Tails", lambda=lambda, num_flips=num_flips))
            p <- p / 2  # reduce the probability of heads by half
        }
    }
    # if no heads were observed in this set, generate a new Poisson random number centered around the previous num_flips
    lambda <- num_flips
    num_flips <- rpois(1, lambda)
    p <- 0.5  # reset the probability of heads
    set <- set + 1  # increment the set number
}
}


results <- flipCoinPoissonTimes()
print(results)

results$iteration = 1

results$total_turns = 1:nrow(results)

final = results

I am trying to run this code 100 times and store all the results in a single vertical dataframe (with all columns, including iteration and total_turns).
I tried this code:
> replicate(100, flipCoinPoissonTimes())

But its not producing the correct result.
Can someone show me how to do it correctly?

Try replicate(100, flipCoinPoissonTimes(), simplify=FALSE).

@ jay.sf: thanks ... but I want these final 2 variables added to each replicate:

results$iteration = 1
results$total_turns = 1:nrow(results)

see below: I just tried something using lapply

Try purrr::map_dfr:
library(tidyverse) 
set.seed(10)

# with your original function, without arguments
my_results <- map_dfr(
  1:100,
  \(x) mutate(
    bind_cols(tibble(iteration = x), flipCoinPoissonTimes()), 
    total_turns = row_number()))

Output:
> my_results %>% filter(iteration <= 6) %>% print(n = nrow(.))
# A tibble: 25 × 8
   iteration   set turn_number value_of_p result lambda num_flips total_turns
       <int> <dbl>       <int>      <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>     <int>       <int>
 1         1     1           1    0.5     Heads       5         5           1
 2         2     1           1    0.5     Tails       5         4           1
 3         2     1           2    0.25    Heads       5         4           2
 4         3     1           1    0.5     Heads       5         3           1
 5         4     1           1    0.5     Tails       5         4           1
 6         4     1           2    0.25    Tails       5         4           2
 7         4     1           3    0.125   Tails       5         4           3
 8         4     1           4    0.0625  Tails       5         4           4
 9         4     2           1    0.5     Tails       4         2           5
10         4     2           2    0.25    Tails       4         2           6
11         4     3           1    0.5     Heads       2         2           7
12         5     1           1    0.5     Heads       5         3           1
13         6     1           1    0.5     Tails       5         7           1
14         6     1           2    0.25    Tails       5         7           2
15         6     1           3    0.125   Tails       5         7           3
16         6     1           4    0.0625  Tails       5         7           4
17         6     1           5    0.0312  Tails       5         7           5
18         6     1           6    0.0156  Tails       5         7           6
19         6     1           7    0.00781 Tails       5         7           7
20         6     2           1    0.5     Tails       7         5           8
21         6     2           2    0.25    Tails       7         5           9
22         6     2           3    0.125   Tails       7         5          10
23         6     2           4    0.0625  Tails       7         5          11
24         6     2           5    0.0312  Tails       7         5          12
25         6     3           1    0.5     Heads       5         8          13


@ Adriano : thanks for the answer ... what do you think of my answer? is it also correct?

@konofoso If your solution delivers the expected result, then it is correct! Of course, there are other considerations, such as whether the speed is good enough for the application, whether the code is readable and easy to understand, and whether the functions and packages used are still current.

@konofoso I gave you a tidyverse solution, but you should always look for base-r alternatives too (and choose what’s better for your problem)!

My own attempt to solve this using lapply:
flipCoinPoissonTimes <- function(iteration) {
    lambda <- 5  # initial parameter for the Poisson distribution
    num_flips <- rpois(1, lambda)  # generate a random number from a Poisson distribution

p <- 0.5  # initial probability of heads
set <- 1  # initial set number
results <- data.frame(set=integer(), turn_number=integer(), value_of_p=numeric(), result=character(), lambda=numeric(), num_flips=integer(), iteration=integer())

while(TRUE) {
    for (turn_number in 1:num_flips) {
        flip <- runif(1)  # generate a random number between 0 and 1
        if (flip < p) {
            results <- rbind(results, data.frame(set=set, turn_number=turn_number, value_of_p=p, result="Heads", lambda=lambda, num_flips=num_flips, iteration=iteration))
            return(results)  # stop once the first head is observed
        } else {
            results <- rbind(results, data.frame(set=set, turn_number=turn_number, value_of_p=p, result="Tails", lambda=lambda, num_flips=num_flips, iteration=iteration))
            p <- p / 2  # reduce the probability of heads by half
        }
    }
    # if no heads were observed in this set, generate a new Poisson random number centered around the previous num_flips
    lambda <- num_flips
    num_flips <- rpois(1, lambda)
    p <- 0.5  # reset the probability of heads
    set <- set + 1  # increment the set number
}
}

Now, I launch the function:
# lapply
all_results <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:100, function(i) {
    result <- flipCoinPoissonTimes(i)
    result$total_turns <- 1:nrow(result)
    return(result)
}))

As a bonus, I plot the results (keep last row for each iteration):
library(dplyr)

last_rows <- all_results %>%
  group_by(iteration) %>%
  filter(row_number() == n())


# Reshape 
all_results_long <- last_rows %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = c(turn_number, value_of_p, lambda, num_flips, total_turns), 
                 names_to = "variable", 
                 values_to = "value")

# Plot 
ggplot(all_results_long, aes(x = log(value), color = variable, fill = variable)) +
    geom_density(alpha = 0.3) +
    labs(title = "Density Distributions of Various Columns",
         x = "Value",
         y = "Density") +
    theme_minimal()


